# Getting Bluetooth 5.4 to work on HAOS (Home Assistant OS)

Tags: bluetooth, home-assistant

I'd like to use Bluetooth in my Smart Home setup, which is based on a Home Assistant green bridge and runs the latest HAOS (2024.3.1). According to https://github.com/home-assistant/operating-system/releases, this is running a 6.6.20 Linux kernel.

To add BT support, HA advertises to just buy and plug in a compatible BT dongle and lists working devices here: https://www.home-assistant.io/integrations/bluetooth/

Problem is that this list is kinda outdated and the listed working devices are hard to find on the market today (They are mostly BT 4.0, while most things you can get online are 5.x).

So I bought a BT 5.4 dongle (specifically the UGREEN CM748) in the hopes of getting it to work on HAOS - which of course failed.

Now I assume that buying/trying another more recent model will result in the same problem, which leads me to my question:

**- How do I get a more recent BT dongle to work on HAOS?**

As far as I understand, this is the problem of the drivers not being available.

**- Which BT 5.4 dongles bring Linux compatibility and would work with HAOS?**

I read about the ESP32-integration but honestly shy away from "building" and programming my own device here. What I want is a ordinary dongle for the HAOS doing the work.

Comment: You might want to stop by the [HomeAssistant Discord server](https://discord.gg/5XPer8zz) (Discord invite), in particular the #Green or #Hardware channels. You're more likely to get accurate and timely input there. TBH, this stack has never been particularly active and seems to be getting less & less so.